# Unable to use webpack analyser to create build

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am trying to use webpack to analyze my bundles, but I am unable to do so. Get the following errors. How can I fix this?

[image]

The contents of my JSON are as follows. I am posting the errors that am receiving on git

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --disable-host-check",
    "start:local": "BACKEND=http://localhost:3000 webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --ext mjs,jsx,js --format codeframe \".*.js\" src test",
    "coverage": "nyc --all jest --collectCoverage",
    "codecov": "rm -rf .nyc_output/ && yarn coverage && nyc report --reporter=text-lcov && codecov",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build"
  },
  "
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: webpack requires that you use unix style new lines, but it found windows style new lines.

This error is when compiling index.jsx, so the json is irrelevant.

Comment: Made a few changes and now I am able to create a build but no info is showing. The following error:
No bundles were parsed. Analyzer will show only original module sizes from stats file.

Webpack Bundle Analyzer is started at http://127.0.0.1:8888
Use Ctrl+C to close it

Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 4968172b96b83b06dca5
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 58ms
Built at: 03/16/2020 4:48:31 PM

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\romibabe\documents\fire********